# unable to invoke mod_rest of jabberd,

Tags: ejabberd

i have setup a ejabberd server and enable the mod_rest. i could start ejabberd without problem. however if i invoke the rest service,

i have google module_must_be_started_in_vhost, but no luck. anyone could help?

---

### Error from ejabberbctl live

22:18:13.881 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.492.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: {module_must_be_started_in_vhost,mod_rest,<<"xjt.cloudapp.net">>} in mod_rest:try_get_option/3 line 107
22:18:13.881 [error] Supervisor ejabberd_http_sup had child undefined started with {ejabberd_http,start_link,undefined} at <0.492.0> exit with reason {module_must_be_started_in_vhost,mod_rest,<<"xjt.cloudapp.net">>} in context child_terminated

---

```
  -
port: 5285
module: ejabberd_http
hosts:
    - "xjt.cloudapp.net"
request_handlers:
    "/rest": mod_rest
```

Comment: anyone get this before?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed mod_rest?

I think this is right..

> ejabberdctl modules_update_specs
>
> ejabberdctl module_install mod_rest

Comment: I have also get same error. and mod_rest is already installed

Comment: you saved my life